# Why does my ko computed observable not update bound UI elements when its value changes?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, computed-observable

I'm trying to wrap a cookie in a computed observable (which I'll later turn into a protectedObservable) and I'm having some problems with the computed observable.  I was under the opinion that changes to the computed observable would be broadcast to any UI elements that have been bound to it.

I've created [the following fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/allen/2JWBf/13/)

**JavaScript**:

```
var viewModel = {};

// simulating a cookie store, this part isnt as important
var cookie = function () {  

    // simulating a value stored in cookies
    var privateZipcode = "12345";

    return {
        'write' : function (val) { privateZipcode = val; }, 
        'read': function () { return privateZipcode; }
    }
}();

viewModel.zipcode = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return cookie.read();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            cookie.write(value);
        },
        owner: viewModel
    });

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);?
```

**HTML**:

```
zipcode:
<input type='text' data-bind="value: zipcode"> <br />

zipcode: 
<span data-bind="text: zipcode"></span>?
```

I'm not using an observable to store `privateZipcode` since that's really just going to be in a cookie.  I'm hoping that the `ko.computed` will provide the notifications and binding functionality that I need, though most of the [examples I've seen](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) with `ko.computed` end up using a `ko.observable` underneath the covers.

Shouldn't the act of writing the value to my computed observable signal the UI elements that are bound to its value?  Shouldn't these just update?

### Workaround

I've got a simple workaround where I just use a `ko.observable` along side of my cookie store and using that will trigger the required updates to my DOM elements but this seems completely unnecessary, unless `ko.computed` lacks the signaling / dependency type functionality that `ko.observable` has.

[My workaround fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/allen/jh4qN/3/), you'll notice that the only thing that changes is that I added a `seperateObservable` that isn't used as a store, its only purpose is to signal to the UI that the underlying data has changed.

```
// simulating a cookie store, this part isnt as important
var cookie = function () {  

    // simulating a value stored in cookies
    var privateZipcode = "12345";

    // extra observable that isnt really used as a store, just to trigger updates to the UI
    var seperateObservable = ko.observable(privateZipcode);

    return {
        'write' : function (val) { 
            privateZipcode = val; 
            seperateObservable(val);
        }, 
        'read': function () { 
            seperateObservable();
            return privateZipcode; 
        }
    }
}();
```

This makes sense and works as I'd expect because `viewModel.zipcode` depends on `seperateObservable` and updates to that should (and does) signal the UI to update.  **What I don't understand,** is why doesn't a call to the `write` function on my `ko.computed` signal the UI to update, since that element is bound to that `ko.computed`?

I suspected that I might have to use something in knockout to manually signal that my `ko.computed` has been updated, and I'm fine with that, that makes sense.  I just haven't been able to find a way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

sigh, I found someone with [my exact same problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knockoutjs/bX8ze5S1w8o/discussion)

> If dependentObservables don't notifySubscribers on write, why do they
>   even bother to do it on read? They get added to the observables list
>   and subscribed to, but then they never trigger on updates. So what is
>   the point of subscribing to them at all?

[Ryan Niemeyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594420/rp-niemeyer) answers:

> I think that for your scenario, dependentObservables may not be the
>   right tool for the job.  dependentObservables are set up to detect
>   dependencies in the read function and re-evaluate/notify whenever any
>   of those dependencies change.  In a writeable dependentObservable, the
>   write function is really just a place to intercept the write and allow
>   you to set any observables necessary, such that your read function
>   would return the proper value (write is typically the reverse of read
>   in most cases, unless you are transforming the value).
>
> For your case, I would personally use an observable to represent the
>   value and then a manual subscription to that observable to update the
>   original value (the one that you may not have control over).
>
> It would be like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Nn5TH/

So it looks like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/allen/jh4qN/4/) would be a solution

```
var viewModel = {};

// simulating a cookie store, this part isnt as important
var cookie = function () {  

    // simulating a value stored in cookies
    var privateZipcode = "12345";

    return {
        'write' : function (val) { 
            console.log("updated cookie value with: " + val);
            privateZipcode = val; 
        }, 
        'read': function () { 
            return privateZipcode; 
        }
    }
}();

viewModel.zipcode = ko.observable(cookie.read());

// manually update the cookie when the observable changes
viewModel.zipcode.subscribe(function(newValue) {
   cookie.write(newValue);   
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);​
```

That makes sense and its somewhat simpler to use.  Overall I'm not sure how great of an idea it is to treat a cookie as an observable since the server could edit it in an ajax request, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your internal privatezipcode an observable. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/KodeKreachor/fAGes/9/

Comment: it's really writing / reading that value via `$.cookie.get()` and `$.cookie.set()`, simulated via `cookie` in my example.  I don't have the ability to make that an observable, aside from what i'm trying to do in my `ko.computed` observable itself.  The idea is that `ko.computed` would encapsulate the writing to / reading from the cookie, which is why I'm not a big fan of using `subscribe`.

Comment: Right, but if your cookie object doesn't have anything intrinsic to it that the knockout dependency tracking system can track then you're probably out of luck. If you just make your internal privateZipcode an observable then you should be able to see the value update.

Comment: So the cookie object itself isn't an observable, it only contains an observable so that it can be tracked when it is written to.

Comment: Essentially you are suggesting the same thing that Niemeyer is, and I'll def +1 for that.  He takes it a step farther (and this is what I was getting at) by basically saying "store it in an observable and subscribe to it".  By doing that, it completely eliminates the need to have a `ko.computed` at all.  That's the only difference in the two approaches.